# What is preventing this function from working?

Tags: javascript

Error: expected an identifier and instead saw 'if'

```
    let min = (a,b) => 
      if (a < b) {
        return a;
      }
      else if (b < a) {
        return b;
      }
      else {
        console.log("error");
      };
```

Comment: It needs brackets

Comment: Generating an error for asking for the min of two equal elements is unusual to say the least.